# Multiple checkbox click data display

Tags: javascript, postgresql, jsp, checkbox

I am using JSP and PostgreSQL, My data tables are stored in the database, I display the table names as checkboxes in webpage I am trying to do is if I click checkbox it automatically displays data stores in the database, If I click more than one check boxes then it will display all table data How to create function for this one if user click checkboxes then automatically the page is replaced with data.

It is for displaying table names stored in the database.

```
<div class="container">
<!-- JSP Code for populating checkboxes box starts here  -->
    <%
        while (rset.next()) {
    %>
         <input type="checkbox" /> <%value= rset.getString(1)%> <br />   
    <%
        } //while loop ends here 
    %>
<!-- JSP Code for populating drop down box ends here  -->
</div>
```

How to create function in JSP for multiple checkbox click and automatic display of data without using any submit button.

Answer (score 0):

you can acquire this from jsp code in dynamic way.
so better go to javascript ajax call.

when you click on the checkbox ,and get the value of check box and do the necessary step in your action or servlet.

and get back the data and display the table in the success of ajax function.